# If minimum of independent random variable is exponential, is each one exponential?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, exponential-distribution

We know that that given $X_1,...,X_n$ independent random variables which are distributed exponentially, their minimum is also distributed exponentially. Is the converse true? Given $X = \min\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ distributed exponentially, and $X_1, ..., X_n$ are independent, is it true that $X_i$ is distributed exponentially for all $i = 1,...,n$?

Edit: I don't assumme the $X_i$'s are identically distributed. I believe it is true that if $X \sim \exp(\lambda)$, and if $p_i \equiv \mathbb{P}(X_i = X)$ then $X_i \sim \exp(\lambda p_i)$. However, I couldn't find a reference and didn't manage to prove this by myself.

Further edit: The result is true if you assume $\{X = X_i\}$ is an event independent of $X$. This is proven in the following manner:

1. Construct a Poisson process $N_t$ whose waiting times are IID copies of $X$.
2. Split this Poisson process to $n$ counting processes - the process $N_t^i$ will count the number of occurences where $X = X_i$.
3. Using the fact that $\{X = X_i\}$ is an event independent of $X$, and that $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent random variables, one can show that $N_t^i$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda p_i$.
4. The waiting times of $N_t^i$ will be distributed as $\exp(\lambda p_i)$, but on the other hand, they will be equal to $X_i$.

Comment: Yes, and the proof is straightforward. Please show your attempt.

Comment: It is one of known characterizations of the Exponential distribution by order statistics: see here https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-42/issue-2/A-Characterization-of-the-Exponential-Distribution-by-Order-Statistics/10.1214/aoms/1177693444.full

Comment: I tried to calculate the CDF of $X_i$ by conditioing on the index where the minimum is achived. But I don't understand how to calculate this term - what is the probability that $X_i$ is smaller than t given that the minimum is X_j?

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified - I address the case where $X_i$'s are not assumed to be identically distributed.

Comment: @Eran Have you checked the case $n=2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Example:** Let $\lambda_1:[0,\infty)\to(0,1)$ be a continuous function, and then define $\lambda_2(t):=1-\lambda_1(t)$. Also define  $\Lambda_k(t):=\int_0^t\lambda_k(s)\,ds$ for $t\ge 0$ and $k=1,2$. Then $F_k(t) :=1-\exp(-\Lambda_k(t))$, $t\ge 0$, are distribution functions of non-negative random variables, say $X_1$ and $X_2$. Their minimum  $X:=\min(X_1,X_2)$ has cdf $1-(1-F_1(t))\cdot(1-F_2(t))=1-e^{-t}$, $t\ge 0$.  Thus $X$ is exponentially distributed, but the $X_k$ need not be.

Comment: A non-trivial counterexample!

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, if $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent non-negative random variables such that the minimum of each pair of them is exponentially distributed, then each of the random variables is exponentially distributed.

(Pairwise independence suffices.)